# Geofire Android: How to add multiple locations to one child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

Does anybody know how to add location data for more than one location to a child under a geofire node?

For example, if I wanted to search for the closest McDonald's to my location, is it possible to store the latitude and longitude of different McDonald's restaurants under the same McDonald's node in my Firebase Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoFire associates keys with locations.

Keys can be arbitrary values, you determine what they mean. But a single key can have a single location.

If you want to store multiple locations for a single restaurant, you'll have to give them a different key.